# PHP class value not accessible after initializing

Tags: php

I am trying to turn an input file in the form below into a series of objects that can be manipulated.

```
arabian_sea_area = {
    1926 1927 1931 1932 1933 2029 2030 
}

gulf_of_aden_sea_area = {
    1925 2024 5285 5286 
}
```

sdf

```
<?php

$all_areas = array();
if (($handle = fopen("area.txt", "r")) == False)
{
   die("failed to open file\n");
}

while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== FALSE)
{
    if (ctype_alpha($line[0]))
    {
        $line= explode(" ",$line);
       // echo($line[0]."\n");

        $area = $line[0]; 
        $IDs = explode(" ", fgets($handle));
        $IDs[0] = ltrim($IDs[0], '  '); // trying to remove tab from first ID
        $all_areas[$area] = $IDs;
        //array_push($all_areas, $temp);
    }
}
//echo("a\n");
print_r($all_areas["arabian_sea_area"]);
//var_dump ($all_areas);

?>
```

The values print correctly in the commented out debug lines but fail to print anything for the var_dump at the end.

edit: I realize this was unclear, what I was trying to do was create a master "all_areas" array that linked to objects titled the first line (ie. arabian_sea_area etc.) and I could then get at the numerical Ids for each area algorithmically for a later script.

Comment: Please add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many issues with your code:

1-

```
if (ctype_alpha($line[0]))
{
    $line= explode(" ",$line);
    //echo($line[0]."\n");

    $temp = $line[0]; 
    $temp = new Area;
    $temp->filler($line, $handle);
}
```

you are creating a $temp variable but you forgot to push it to your main array $all_areas. use array_push

2-

```
var_dump ($arabian_sea_area);
```

$arabian_sea_area does not exist. 
Did you mean to print your main array $all_areas ?

3- Recommendation:

On errors (echo("failed to open file\n");) its recommended to use die("failed to open file\n"); instead of echo. as die will stop the rest of the script from executing.

-- UPDATE --

I edited your code in a way that should work fine:

```
   class Area  {
    public $area_name;
    public $IDs = array();

    public function filler($line, $handle) {
        $this->area_name = $line[0];
        //echo($this->area_name."\n");

        $this->IDs = explode(" ", fgets($handle));
        //print_r($this->IDs);
    }
}
$all_areas = array();
if (($handle = fopen("area.txt", "r")) == False)
{
   die("failed to open file\n");
}

while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== FALSE)
{
    if (ctype_alpha($line[0]))
    {
        $line= explode(" ",$line);
       // echo($line[0]."\n");

        $temp = $line[0]; 
        $temp = new Area;
        $temp->filler($line, $handle);

        array_push($all_areas, $temp);
    }
}
//echo("a\n");
var_dump ($all_areas);
```

You might wanna update it to remove / filter empty values.

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there a way to make the $all_arrays an associative array holding area_name and IDs?

Comment: I'm not sure i understand what do you mean. $all_arrays should be now an array of Area objects.
Please elaborate on what are you looking for.

Comment: I actually didn't need the class at all. The idea was to be able to input an area name like arabian sea and output an array of IDs that correspond with that area. It's currently working as intended, only I can't seem to remove the tab or the trailing empty IDs index very well.  And thank you very much for you're help, as you can surely tell I'm new to programing and PHP in particular!

Comment: Just use trim in your filler function. I made an example:       




public function filler($line, $handle) {
        $this->area_name = trim($line[0]);
        //echo($this->area_name."\n");

        $this->IDs = explode(" ", trim(fgets($handle)));
        //print_r($this->IDs);
    }